# Regex Between Two Parentheses

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to import some Oracle SQL data into my MySQL database.  At the moment I am using Notepad++ and the regular expression search feature to try and delete the timestamp information stored in each row. I have tried, unsuccessfully, to find the regular expression that would isolate the timestamp portion of this line and was wondering if someone could help.

```
values (4,21,22,221164,165375,0,0,21,144,0,0,605,to_timestamp('07-JAN-14 10.49.42.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),to_timestamp('07-JAN-14 10.49.42.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),'PROG',null);
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. We can't tell what you're doing wrong if you don't show it.

Comment: You should tag your question with `Notepad++`

Comment: I've removed the sql and mysql tags. Where the data came from is irrelevant to designing the regexp to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `to_timestamp(...)` you can use the following regex

```
to_timestamp\(.*?\)
```

Here you have the working example:

http://regex101.com/r/zK6lC5/1

Comment: You made that look super easy compared to my builds.  Thank you.

Comment: @Neggly lol glad to help you. The trick here was the use of non greedy * operator.